# Simple Maven / Eclipse approach for processing resources using shell command

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I have a simple pre-processing step that infrequently needs to be performed on some resources in a Maven/Eclipse project, this involves a simple OS command using a utility executable, for example:

```
glslc triangle.frag -o spv.triangle.frag
```

The `glslc` executable processes the `triangle.frag` shader module and generates the `spv.triangle.frag` output file (in the same directory).

Ideally I would like a maven goal that performed the above for all modified .frag files within a given directory structure, rather than having to switch to a terminal, or create shell scripts, etc.

I assume an ANT plugin for Maven is the way to go (assuming that's the simplest and most common mechanism available).  I have tried adding a maven `antrun` plugin but I'm struggling to work out how to configure it for multiple/modified files.  I'm sure it's relatively straight-forward but it's been a *long* time since I've had to fiddle with ANT and I'm at a bit of a loss where to start.  Had a look online but can't find any decent examples or tutorials, probably because I'm not searching for the right things.

Note that the files do not change that much but it would be very convenient to have a quick-and-dirty (or hot-deploy) means of generating the output file file(s) that have changed.

Also note that these resources **do not** need to be part of the maven build/deploy process, i.e. they are only used during development and testing.

Alternatively is there an equivalent Eclipse mechanism that that can be used to do the same thing?  Again this is a convenience so something relatively 'manual' is fine.

I'm looking for any pointers to relevant examples, tutorials, repos, etc. as a starting point or hint from which I can then implement a solution.

Comment: What about integrating that into a CI process via Jenkins for example? Execution can also being done via exec-maven-plugin ?

Comment: @khmarbaise - Yes I _could_ incorporate it into an automated build (the shaders are used in the test suite).  But the main focus of my question is _how_ do I configure the maven plugin in the first place?  I've looked at exec-maven-plugin but can only find noddy examples and lots and lots of ancient looking ANT documentation.  I'm hoping for an example or tutorial using an exec plugin to transform a number of files using a shell command/script.